# How to make Timer countdown to 00:00, stay on this value for a while and change to another cycle?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Now I’m working on my version of 25 + 5 Clock, this is my version on codepen: https://codepen.io/faber_g/pen/WNJOOwp

And this is example from Freecodecamp and tasks to complete: https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/XpKrrW (example)

https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/front-end-development-libraries/front-end-development-libraries-projects/build-a-25--5-clock (tasks)

The main idea of this timer is when timer countdown to "00:00" it should switch between "Break" and "Session" cycles. I do it in this way:

```
<div  id="time-left" style={this.state.timerAmount < 60 ? { color: 'red' } : { color: 'black' }}>{this.clockInfo() === "00:00" ? this.changeName() : this.clockInfo()}</div>
```

The problem of my code is that it doesn't countdown to "00:00" or it switchs too fast, so you can only see "00:01" and then it changes to new cycle.

First in my function `this.changeName()` I go with this code, but it swithes too fast, so you can not see "00:00":

```
changeName() {
   if (this.state.timerAmount === 0 && this.state.timerName === 'Session') {
        this.playSound();
        setTimeout(() => {this.setState(state => ({
          timerAmount: this.state.breakMinutes * 60,
          timerName: 'Break'
    })); },2000);    
     } 
    else if (this.state.timerAmount === 0 && this.state.timerName === 'Break') {
      this.playSound();
      this.setState(state => ({
         timerAmount: this.state.sessionMinutes * 60,
         timerName: 'Session'
    })); }
  }
```

Then I've tried by using `innerHTML/innerText/innerContent` first stay on "00:00" and after that using `setTimeout` for `this.setState` to change velue for new cycle with delay, but in this case I get empty element for some time and then it is start new cycle:

```
changeName() {
   if (this.state.timerName === 'Session') {
       
        document.getElementById('time-left').innerHTML = "00:00"
        this.playSound();
        setTimeout(() => {this.setState(state => ({
          timerAmount: this.state.breakMinutes * 60,
          timerName: 'Break'
    })); },2000);    
     } 
    else if (this.state.timerName === 'Break') {
      document.getElementById('time-left').innerText = "00:00";
      this.playSound();
      setTimeout(() => {this.setState(state => ({
         timerAmount: this.state.sessionMinutes * 60,
         timerName: 'Session'
    }));} , 2000);
  }
```

How to make Timer countdown to 00:00, stay on this value for a while and change to another cycle?

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.
In `clockInfo()` I have condition `if (timer > 0) return "00:00"`. So when my timer showed "00:00", it start `changeName()` function and that is how I got empty element for some time.

I deleted `changeName()` and isertes it's conditions into `clockInfo()` like this:

```
clockInfo() {
    if (this.state.timerAmount < 0) {
      
      if (this.state.timerName === 'Session') {
        "00:00"
        this.playSound();
        this.setState(state => ({
          timerAmount: this.state.breakMinutes * 60,
          timerName: 'Break'
    }));     
     } else if (this.state.timerName === 'Break') {
       "00:00"
      this.playSound();
      this.setState(state => ({
         timerAmount: this.state.sessionMinutes * 60,
         timerName: 'Session'
    }));
   }
  } else {
    let minutes = Math.floor(this.state.timerAmount / 60);
    let seconds = this.state.timerAmount - minutes * 60;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
    return minutes + ':' + seconds;
    }
   }
```

When timer < 0, first it shaw "00:00", then play sound and then start function, but in this case without any empty element. So now all works very well.